# Quotients preserve monomorphisms in abelian categories

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

We work in an abelian category. I use $f_k$ and $f^k$ to denote the morphisms given by the kernel and cokernel of the map $f$.

[Here's a diagram](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNixbMSwxLCJBIl0sWzAsMiwiQiJdLFsyLDIsIkMiXSxbMCw0LCJCL0EiXSxbMiw0LCJDL0EiXSxbMywwXSxbMCwxLCJmIiwyLHsic3R5bGUiOnsidGFpbCI6eyJuYW1lIjoiaG9vayIsInNpZGUiOiJ0b3AifX19XSxbMCwyLCJnIiwwLHsic3R5bGUiOnsidGFpbCI6eyJuYW1lIjoiaG9vayIsInNpZGUiOiJ0b3AifX19XSxbMSwyLCJoIiwyLHsic3R5bGUiOnsidGFpbCI6eyJuYW1lIjoiaG9vayIsInNpZGUiOiJ0b3AifX19XSxbMSwzLCJmXmsiLDIseyJzdHlsZSI6eyJoZWFkIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJlcGkifX19XSxbMiw0LCJnXmsiLDAseyJzdHlsZSI6eyJoZWFkIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJlcGkifX19XSxbMyw0LCJoJyIsMl1d)

Suppose we have monos $f:A\rightarrow B$, $g:A\rightarrow C$, and $h:B\rightarrow C$. Then $g^khf=g^kg=0$, so $g^kh$ factors uniquely through $f^k$, say via some $h'$. That is, $h'f^k=g^kh$. Must $h'$ be mono?

I want to say yes after mulling it over in the category of modules over a ring, in light of Mitchell's embedding theorem. Is there also an abstract nonsense proof? I'm not really sure how to translate my proof using elements into one about morphisms.

Probably there's also a proof involving commuiting limits and colimits of a certain kind, but I don't know enough about this to come up with the proof myself (but if you do, feel free to share).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be any object, with a morphism $u\colon Y\to B/A$ such that $h'u=0$.  We must show that $u=0$, to deduce that $h'$ is monic.

---

In the special case where the abelian category has enough projectives you can proceed as follows:

Let $P$ be a projective object with epic morphism $p\colon P\to Y$.  By the projective property of $P$ we have a morphism $v\colon P \to B$ such that $f^kv=up$.

---

In the general case, let $P$ and the maps $p\colon P\to Y$, $v\colon P \to B$ be the pullback of $B$ and $Y$ over $B/A$.  Such a pullback exists and $p$ will be epic as it is the pullback of $f^k$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)#Properties)).  By commutativity of the pullback square we have $f^kv=up$.

---

Either way, to deduce that $u=0$ it will suffice to show that $up=0$ (as $p$ is epic).  Our goal now is to show that $v$ factors through $f$ (so $v=fm$), as then we have $up=f^kv=f^kfm=0$.

[image]

We have $g^khv=h'f^kv=h'up=0$.

As $g$ is monic, we have $g=(g^k)_k$, so $g^khv=0$ implies $hv=gm$ for some morphism $m\colon P\to A$.

Then $hv=gm=hfm$.  As $h$ is monic we may conclude that $v=fm$ as was our goal.

Comment: Awesome, this is a really nice and simple proof! Looks like there’s a dual proof for “the other side”? Where h epi implies h’ epi. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, my previous comment is not right, I think. The dual proof proves a different claim (namely if $f:B\rightarrow A$ and $h:C\rightarrow B$ are epi then the induced map $\ker fh\rightarrow\ker f$ is epi). That $h$ epi implies $h'$ epi in this problem is very easy, namely $g^kh=h'f^k$ is then epi, so $h'$ must be as well since $xh'=0\Rightarrow xh'f^k=0\Rightarrow x=0$.

Comment: Yes you are right about both.